# Excel csv-import into table referenced by name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, csv

I have a worksheet called `raw_data` where I import some data via the Data-Import Wizard. This created a new name-referenced range called `abc.csv`.

However if I try to create a table on another worksheet `data` i am not able to reference the name-referenced range `abc.csv`.

How can I convert this named range into a table without loosing the data-connection?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Have a csv-file.
2. Import it with the wizard.
3. Check name in name-manager.
4. Create new worksheet.
5. Create table via wizard and enter the name of your imported data-range

Comment: How about add to data model?

Comment: when " create a table on another worksheet ".. is the 1st worksheet still open?